# Installing gnuplot on Mountain Lion fails

Tags: macos, installation, gnuplot, osx-mountain-lion

I was trying to install gnuplot on OSX 10.8.5 using this instructions:
http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/phy410-505/tools/install/

All steps went fine until the *make* file execution of gnuplot. I ended up with:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_gdImagePng", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  _PNG_text in term.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make[3]: *** [gnuplot] Error 1
>
> make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Any ideas what is wrong here? I tried installing it afterwards with homebrew, but ended up with the same result.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you don't have the correct libraries to elaborate PNGs, have you tried:

```
brew install graphviz
brew install gd
```

or, if they are already installed, you can try:

```
brew unlink gd
brew install -vd graphviz
brew link gd
```